# Server 2008 will not sync with NTP

Tags: windows-server-2008, ntp

I recently got given a server 2008 r1 machine and thought I would set it up to help maintain my small work network of 10 PCs better.

The issue I am having is that I cannot get it to sync with an external time source.

I have done loads of googling and have tried everything I could find.

I have confirmed the server is the PDC

```
NETDOM QUERY /D:nlsc.local FSMO

Schema master JANEWAY.NLSC.local

Domain naming master JANEWAY.NLSC.local

PDC JANEWAY.NLSC.local

RID pool manager JANEWAY.NLSC.local

Infrastructure master JANEWAY.NLSC.local
```

I have tried reseting the service

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
net start w32time
```

I have tried seting peer lists

```
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"uk.pool.ntp.org" /syncfromflags:MANUAL /reliable:yes
```

I have confirmed that the server can access NTP servers

```
w32tm /stripchart /computer:uk.pool.ntp.org /samples:2 /dataonly

Tracking uk.pool.ntp.org [217.114.59.66:123].
Collecting 2 samples.
The current time is 21/02/2014 11:19:30.
11:19:30, -25.2591846s
11:19:33, -25.2494523s
```

I have tried resyncing the service

```
w32tm /resync

Sending resync command to local computer
The computer dud not resync because no time data was available
```

When I try to monitor the service I get

```
w32tm /monitor

Getting AD DC list for default domain...
Analyzing JANEWAY.NLSC.local (1 of 1)...
delayerror ERROR_TIMEOUT - no response from server in 1000ms

JANEWAY.NLSC.local *** PDC ***[[fe80::8d8d:4933:9e57:7ab7%10]:123]:
    ICMP: 0ms 
    NTP:
```

I saw that there is a ip6 address while I am using ip4 so I disabled ip6 from the network adapter but still nothing.

The server is the DNS for the domain with a secondary being the router.
I use pfSense 2.1 release as my router which is also DHCP for the network

Update

```
[Configuration]
EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 10 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 6 (Local)
MaxPollInterval: 10 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 172800 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 172800 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 300 (Local)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 7 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 100 (Local)


[TimeProviders]
NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
CrossSiteSyncFlags: 2 (Policy)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Policy)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Policy)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 0 (Policy)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 1080 (Policy)
Type: NT5DS (Policy)

NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 0 (Policy)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
```

Comment: Can you post the results of `W32tm /query /configuration` ? You may also want to try enabling debug logging. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w32tm.aspx

Comment: hi, new info added